# How to fix '1: No such file or directory'

Tags: bash

How can I compare a variable in bash shell script to less than 1?

I did before, but I get '1: No such file or directory'

```
grep_result=`grep -r $ID . | wc -l`

echo $grep_result
# it said '1: No such file or directory'
if [ $grep_result < 1 ]; then
    echo "Wrong id.
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From bash's perspective this means pipe the file called `1` into the $grep_result variable. You need to use the `-lt` operator in this case. (le stands for less than)

```
grep_result=`grep -r $ID . | wc -l`

echo $grep_result
# it said '1: No such file or directory'
if [ $grep_result -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Wrong id.
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 different ways to change your code:

**Route #1:**

Change your code to:

```
grep_result=$(grep -r $ID .)

echo $grep_result

if [ -z "$grep_result" ]; then
    echo "Wrong id."
    exit 1
fi
```

**Explanation:**

- `grep_result=$(grep -r $ID .)`: Run `grep -r $ID .` in a subshell and save the resultant output to `stdout` to `grep_result`. The `$(...)` notation is called command substitution, and is preferred over use of backticks for improved readability + allowing nesting of commands
- `if [ -z "$grep_result" ]; then`: the `-z` option for the `[` "test" shell built-in checks whether `"$grep_result"` is the empty string; if so, the the condition evaluates to true.

---

**Route #2:**

Or, alternatively:

```
grep_result_count=$(grep -rc $ID .)

echo $grep_result_count

if [ $grep_result_count -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Wrong id."
    exit 1
fi
```

**Explanation:**

- `grep_result_count=$(grep -rc $ID .)`: Similar idea as above, but note that we are using the `-rc` option for `grep` instead of `-r`; the `c` part of the option means "Don't output the lines matched, just output a numerical tally of how many matches are found instead". So in this case you'll get an integer greater than or equal to 0.
- `if [ $grep_result_count -eq 0 ]; then`: the `-eq` option here checks whether the value to the left of it is equal to the value to the right of it. In this case we check if the number of matches from the previous grep command is exactly equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to check for no matches is

```
if ! grep -q -r "$ID" . ; then
    echo Wrong id.
    exit 1
fi
```

That's right: the purpose if `if` is to run a command and check its exit code.  `grep` returns a success exit code if there were matches, and 1 (error) otherwise.  Most Unix tools are written like that, for precisely this purpose.

Getting the count when there are matches is a minor modification:

```
if matches=$(grep -r "$ID" .) ; then
    echo "$matches" | wc -l
else
    echo Wrong Id.
    exit 1
fi
```

Notice the use of `grep -q` to just return an error code and not print anything.  If you just wanted the count out of a single file (or the number of matches per file) `grep -c` prints that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something more efficient:

```
if ! grep -qr "$ID" . ; then
    echo "Wrong id."
    exit 1
fi
```

Hope this helps.

With the `-q` option, `grep` just keeps quiet, stops as soon as it's found the pattern (if it can find it), and outputs a `true` return value if pattern was found, and `false` otherwise. This is probably the most efficient way to solve your problem.